# The "edit" magic link behaves strangely when applied to answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, magic-links

A new user incorrectly used the answer section to attempt to respond to comment feedback on the question. I tried to comment on that answer using the `[edit]` link shorthand, to prompt OP to edit the question instead. However, I found that the resulting link did not work properly. It appeared to open a form for editing the answer, but with a strange panel above the input form that displayed content from the question.

Comment: Sharing a screenshot may help to visualize the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I removed the link from the comment, and forgot what question it was on. I don't really want to create a test question/answer/edit, because that would be a bit disruptive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The edit link does not apply strangely when applied to answers, although it may apply differently than a high-rep user would expect. It's easy to forget what the site looks like to a user with lower reputation, but all users who do not have [full editing privileges](/help/privileges/edit) (under 2000 reputation) edit posts using the full editor. This is located at the `/posts/{post_id}/edit` endpoint. This can be easily accessed by a user of any reputation level by opening the "edit" link in a new tab.

When a user without full edit privileges clicks the edit link on an answer they see exactly what you describe:
[image: Screen capture of the full answer editing page (described below)]

The full answer editor has 6 components:

1. The question title
2. A collapsible region which contains the question
3. A markdown editor for the answer text
4. The client-side markdown preview of the answer text
5. The edit controls including: a place to write an edit comment, a save, and a cancel button
6. Any comments on the answer and an "Add a comment" button

The reason the question is duplicated on this page is so the person editing the answer can refer to the question content without having to navigate back to the question page.

---

Users with above 2000 reputation, on the other hand, interact with the inline editor.

When the page loads, a bit of JavaScript is used to change the behaviour of the `js-edit-post` links. Instead of navigating these users to the full edit page, it loads and incorporates just the necessary editing components directly into the current question page.

[image: Screen capture of the inline answer editing element (described below)]

The inline editor has 3 components:

1. A markdown editor for the answer text
2. The client-side markdown preview of the answer text
3. The edit controls including: a place to write an edit comment, a save, and a cancel button

It does not need to duplicate any information from the page, since you've not navigated away from the question page to make the edit. The inline editor is something that is very easy to take for granted, as it is a much more integrated editing experience and you don't ever need to navigate away from the question page to make post changes. However, it is not the tool the majority of editors use when they edit posts.

---

So, the [edit] magic link behaves exactly like a normal link to edit a post should by sending the user to the answer edit screen. It's only for users over 2000 reputation that the behaviour of the link in the comment does not act like the edit post link included at the bottom of the answer. This is because there is no CSS class (or other indicator) added to the comment which would enable the inline editor for users with full edit privileges.

It's understandable this would seem odd if you're a user who has had over 2000 reputation for a long time and have rarely interacted with the component recently, however, for the majority of users, who normally edit answers this way, it would not seem odd at all. Like in this specific example, the 1-reputation user you left the comment for would see no difference between the [edit] magic link in the comments and the edit button at the bottom of their own answer.

Comment: Why did I see the full editor when clicking the magic link, but the inline editor when clicking the site built-in edit link on the answer, even though both show the same URL when hovered? - Ah, you mean that the built-in link has a CSS class which is checked by the site's JavaScript?

Comment: Correct, JavaScript runs client side after the page loads. For users with access to the inline editor, this prevents the `js-edit-post` link in the post menu from navigating away and instead requests the inline editor. There are no CSS classes added to comments (even magic links) so no JS to prevent you navigating away; it's just a normal link and behaves as such.

Comment: *"This can be easily accessed by a user of any reputation level by opening the "edit" link in a new tab."* Thank you so much! On my phone, the full editor is much more pleasant to work with because it gives me a width of 32 chars rather than 24.